# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when creating NEW Windows Phone project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I have Windows 8 x64 (not pro), VS2012 Pro Update 3, WP8 SDK and cannot create any new Windows Phone project.

I tried the following to no avail (in admin as well as non-admin accounts)
(numerous times, in different permutations)

1. Uninstall all Silverlight SDKs and components
2. Uninstall WP8 SDK
3. Uninstall all VS2012 components
4. Reboot
5. Clean registry
6. Reinstall VS2012 Pro \ Update VS2012 \ WP8 SDK (with reboots each time) Did not work
7. Reinstall VS2012 Pro \ WP8 SDK \ Update VS2012 (with reboots each time) Did not work.
8. Started devenv /ResetSettings (did not help)
9. Started devenv /ResetSkipPkgs (did not help)
10. Updated Silverlight (before\after all installs --different permutations)

Nothing helped.  Exhausted all possible "solutions" listed on various sites.
I can open and run all other project types *EXCEPT* any of Windows Phone template projects.  It does not even create a solution.

Only extensions are Microsoft Web Developer Tools. NuGet Package Manager and Visual Studio Extensions for Windows Library for JavaScript. Clean install, no third party extensions.

Nothing shows up under my Tools > Extensions and Updates > Updates (all updates done)

Answer (score 2):

Finally able to create a new Windows Phone App project!!

Solution: **UNINSTALLED** NuGet (as updates to it did not work)

Since I am a new user, had to wait for 8 hours to be able to post this as an ANSWER

@MohamedThaufeeq, thanks for pointing to that direction. In my earlier attempts, I did not try to open a WinPhone app immediately after uninstalling NuGet.  I did updates on it, did reinstalls of it, but did not remove it completely.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a tools installation problem you can go into Control Panel's Programs, find the SDK there, and choose Repair. Then reboot your computer to play it safe. There are other threads in this forum related to SDK installation problems.  Be sure to follow all the recommendations, including installing the SDK 8.0 last.

https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk

Regarding this error message in the context of having a problem with a specific project build, this can happen sometimes with the Xaml. In which case you can try a Clean build then a Rebuild.

Hope this helps...

Comment: @JohnSalver then you should try these steps.

Comment: I followed every step possible. I did fresh installs\repairs\reinstalls\registry cleaning\reboots\new admin account installation\ all to no avail.  I did not however try to install SDK 7.1.1 ---I simply installed SDK 80 and 801 --do you think I need 7.1.1??

Comment: Sorry its 8.0 only. Have you installed any extensions ?

Comment: Check NuGet is updated ? This may be happens because of this sometimes

Comment: NuGet is updated too. Even uninstalled it and reinstalled it. Nothing shows up under my Tools > Extensions and Updates > Updates.

Comment: OK. Finally able to create a *new* Windows Phone App project!!

Solution: **UNINSTALLED** NuGet (as updates to it did not work) Since I am a new user, have to wait for 8 hours to be able to post this as an ANSWER

Answer (score 1):

There wasn't any updated for NuGet. But uninstalling it from (tool->Extensions and Updates) and then re-installing it worked for me.